# jquery ui tool tip show only first word

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, razor, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I am using jquery ui tooltip for a dynamically populated title attribute. I am seeing only first word as tool tip instead of complete sentence. What may be my mistake?

```
@defaultTitle="This is a test Title"

<div title=@((defaultTitle == "") ? "Edit" : defaultTitle)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that this happens. It would be nice to know the reason for this odd behavior, but for now, wrap the title's razor implementation in quotes and it will work.

```
@defaultTitle="This is a test Title"

<div title='@((defaultTitle == "") ? "Edit" : defaultTitle)'>
```